# Zend Framework 2 SOAP not compatible with .NET

Tags: c#, php, .net, soap, zend-framework2

I'm trying to create a SOAP server in my ZF2 application that I can import with Visual Studio using the wizard into a C# application. I've already created the service and tested it using soapUI. I ran the WS-I compliance test in soapUI and my service passed it. However, when I try to add the service into a C# application using Visual C# Express 2008, it says that the HTML document does not have webservice discovery information.

Here is the code I'm using in my ZF2 controller:

```
public function exampleAction() {
  if (isset($_GET['wsdl'])) {
    $soapAutoDiscover = new AutoDiscover();
    $soapAutoDiscover->setBindingStyle(array('style' => 'document'));
    $soapAutoDiscover->setOperationBodyStyle(array('use' => 'literal'));
    $soapAutoDiscover->setClass('SoapClass');
    $soapAutoDiscover->setUri($serverUrl);
    echo $soapAutoDiscover->generate()->toXml();
  } else {
    $soap = new Server($serverUrl . '?wsdl');
    $soap->setClass('SoapClass');
    $soap->handle();
  }
}
```

This is the SoapClass class:

```
class SoapClass{

  /**
   * returns the sum of two parameters
   * @param int $a
   * @param int $b
   * @return int
   */
  public function sum ($a, $b){
    return $a + $b;
  }

  /**
   * twice function doc
   * @param int $a
   * @return int
   */
  public function twice($a){
    return $a * 2;
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading and re-reading over and over again the few posts and documentation I found on this, finally came across with de solution:

The SoapClass is fine, but at the moment of generating the wsdl and the server I had to make some changes:

```
public function exampleAction() {
  if (isset($_GET['wsdl'])) {
    //this is new:
    $soapAutoDiscover = new AutoDiscover(new \Zend\Soap\Wsdl\ComplexTypeStrategy\ArrayOfTypeSequence());
    $soapAutoDiscover->setBindingStyle(array('style' => 'document'));
    $soapAutoDiscover->setOperationBodyStyle(array('use' => 'literal'));
    $soapAutoDiscover->setClass('SoapClass');
    $soapAutoDiscover->setUri($serverUrl);
    //so this is:
    header("Content-Type: text/xml");
    echo $soapAutoDiscover->generate()->toXml();
  } else {
    $soap = new Server($serverUrl . '?wsdl');
    //drop this:
    //$soap->setClass('SoapClass');
    //and instead, add this:
    $soap->setObject(new DocumentLiteralWrapper(new SoapClass()));
    $soap->handle();
  }
}
```

Comment: I did what you said, still can not import to visual studio! Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to specify the transport:

```
$style = array('style'=>'document', 'transport'=>'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http');
$soapAutoDiscover->setBindingStyle($style);
```

And the header should be:

```
header('Content-type: application/soap+xml');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can read about several issues regarding the compatibility of ZF SOAP component:

http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-6349